# Solution to the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the solution for the differential equation $\frac{dz}{dt}$ = $z^{\alpha}$ for some $0<\alpha<1$. Can anyone help me out here!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a separable equation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $z^{-\alpha}\,dz=dt$. Integrate. On the left-hand side you have a power. The right-hand side is even simpler. Don't forget the "$C$" (on one side only is fine).

Answer (score 1):

This is a separable differential equation. Divide both sides by $z^\alpha$:
$$
z^{-\alpha} \frac{dz}{dt} = 1
$$

Thus:
$$
\int z^{-\alpha} \, {dz} = \int \, dt
$$

Integrate to get:
$$
\frac{z^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha} = t + c
$$

One thing to note here, when we divided by $z^\alpha$, we assumed that $z$ was not the constant function $0$. This function is also a solution to the differential equation. The constant of integration often takes care of "incorporating" this extra solution into the general one, but it's not the case here.